# How do I save textarea content in laravel on shared hosting?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am working this laravel project `"mealscorner.co.ke"`. I am adding quotations in this page"mealscorner.co.ke/quotations/create" and viewing them here`"mealscorner.co.ke/home"`.
When working on the localhost I would copy order items and paste them in the CKEditor and save to the database perfectly as HTML. When I hosted the project, the content(which includes images) in the CKEditor is not saved-when I enter some text it is saved.

**This is the store function**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $quotation = new Quotation;
    $quotation->quotation_details = $request->quotation_details;
    $quotation->quotation_address = $request->quotation_address;
    $quotation->save();
}
```

**This is the database migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('quotations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->longText('quotation_details', 4000000000);
        $table->string('quotation_address');
        $table->timestamps();
});
}
```

This is an image of the content(inside the text area) I want to save.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMgSh.png)

**This is the HTML code for the form**

```
                <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('quotations.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                    <label for="">Order Items</label><br>
                    <textarea class="form-control ckeditor_form" id="quotations" name="quotation_details" ></textarea>

                    <label for="">Address</label><br>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="quote" name="quotation_address" ></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit"  id="submit" value="Save">
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: have you check the permission of folder in which you are uploading images.

Comment: I am not saving actual images. I am saving their links to the database.

Comment: When you enter some text in the CKEditor, is all of your information in the editor saved or just the part you added? And could you share the HTML of your form?

Comment: when i enter text in CKEditor it is saved all of it. But when I copy-paste the content with images, it does not save anything.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the change event of the CKEditor is nog triggered when pasting content in the editor. Seems like it is only triggered when you enter a new character into the editor. And it could be that you need some additional configuration for pasting: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/drop_paste.html
Sadly I don't know a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

On my own box I would be setting the permissions via SSH which you might still be able to do.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

However with shared hosting you might have to do it via the control panel.

That could be one of your issues. are you able to check the logs?

Comment: in the folder `storage/logs/` laravel creates logs here. if there are none its 100% permissions, larvel on a shared hosting service is a pain in the ass

Comment: local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'quotation_details' cannot be null